# Select2 change attr in second select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How I can change an attribute of an `<option>` in my second `<select>` when the same value was selected in the first `<select>`?

More specifically: When I select an option in my first `<select>`, then the same option in the second `<select>` should be disabled.

```js
$("body").on("select2:select", "#first", function(e) {
  var cur_id = e.params.data.id;
  $("#second").children("option[value=" + cur_id + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#second").trigger('refresh');
  $("#first").trigger('refresh');
});

$("body").on("select2:select", "#second", function(e) {
  var cur_id = e.params.data.id;
  $("#first").children("option[value=" + cur_id + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#second").trigger('refresh');
  $("#first").trigger('refresh');
});
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="first" name="first">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="second" name="second">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a consise way to do it.

```js
$("select#first").on("change", function() {
  $("select#second option").each(function() {
    if ($("select#first option:selected").val() === $(this).val()) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    else $(this).prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select id="first" name="first">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="second" name="second">
    <option value="1" disabled="disabled">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

You might want to automatically select (kick to) another option too in your 2nd select when a user selects the option that is selected in the 2nd `select`. If that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

For select2 version >= 4.0.0

*Solution:*

```
$("select").val("1").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").on("change", "#first", function(e) {//use change event
  var cur_id = $('option:selected',this).val();//get value of selected option
  console.log(cur_id);
  $(this).siblings("#second").children("option[value=" + cur_id + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");//disable from sibling the selected option
});

$("body").on("change", "#second", function(e) {//use change event
  var cur_id = $('option:selected',this).val();//get value of selected option
  console.log(cur_id);
  $(this).siblings("#first").children("option[value=" + cur_id + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");//disable from sibling the selected option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select id="first" name="first">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="second" name="second">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```